# Having problem installing dlib in anaconda

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, dlib

It shows this:

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be
>   incompatible with each other:
>
> pip -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']`

I have tried already answered questions in stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Try using a virtual environment in [conda](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/). Just look up what the dependencies of dlib are and see what version of python is needed. (take it as a comment and not a guaranteed solution)